# Find exact values in excel and paste value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find and match two values from two different sheets. If it can find the value then paste a cell from sheet 1 into sheet 2.

For example.

```
Sheet 1
A1 - 1   B1 - £5
A2 - 2   B2 - £2
A3 - 3   B3 - £4
A4 - 4   B4 - £1

Sheet 2
A1 - 1
A2 - 2
A3 - 4
A4 - 3
```

So it'd look up matching values from Sheet 1 and paste the corresponding cell into Sheet 2. I can seem only find if it's in order, if sheet 1 is not in sheet 2 it produces errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide a reproducible answer so people can try it out themselves to see if it works.

Comment: I suspect you want a VLOOKUP like `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)` in sheet 2 cell B1 which you can copy down.